# Sample TeapotNativeActivity from ndk directory does not display correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I imported sample (i.e. `TeapotNativeActivity`) from `ndk-r10d/samples` directory to Eclipse environment. But when I launch this app on device (i.e. Nexus 7) I get a wrong drawing, see pictures below.

Wrong view:
[image]
[image]

correct view:
[image]

If I enable MSAAx4 in android UI in developer tools - the program works fine. Anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded android-ndk samples from [android samples](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/samples/index.html). I opened the project "Teapot" from samples, compile and execute it via android studio + ndk-r11b, then run it on nexus 7 2013 (android 6.0.1) and all work fine. 
I just used android stuio + ndk-r11b.